# moving between 2 UIViewControllers each with 1 UIView - XCode5 osx

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, uiviewcontroller, xcode5

I started writing a project without really using the storyboard (as i was following a tutorial about creating an options menu for a game).

So i am trying to retroactively implement a way of moving between 2 `UIViewController`s (`MainGame` and `MatchScreen`) that each has a `UIView` (`MainMenu` and `VSComputer` respectively).

Now in the `MainMenu` UIView I have created 4 buttons, with all their positions and settings, two of which are subviews - options and stats - that so appear and disappear when clicked on the current ViewController.

Now, the problem is, I need to somehow move from the main menu to the match screen using one of the other buttons named 'matchScreen'. I feel there must be something that i'm missing as no answer found in my research has worked for me yet.

I have embedded my main `UIViewController` with a `navController` (as suggested in other questions that i've seen) and then added a push segue to the 2nd ViewController. But i don't know how to make this apparent to my code. My code recognises nothing that i do in the storyboard it seems.

```
@interface JDTHMainMenu(){

JDTHOptionsScreen *theOptionScreen;
JDTHPlayerStats *thePlayerStatsScreen;
UIButton *optionScreenButton;
UIButton *matchScreenButton;
UIButton *deckScreenButton;
UIButton *statsScreenButton;
bool isPhone;
bool isOptionScreenOpen;
bool isPlayerStatsScreenOpen;
bool matchScreenButtonPressed;
UIView *tint;
int screenWidth;
int screenHeight;

AppData *appData;
```

}

So to be clear, JDTHMainMenu is a UIView in the JDTHViewController - the original, JDTHMatchScreen is the second ViewController and there is a UIView called JDTHVersusScreen. Im trying to go from one to the other. Also the JDTHAppDelegate only has return YES in the didFinishLaunching method. I feel i'm getting closer....but perhaps not...

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    appData = [AppData sharedData];
    NSLog(@"Main Menu has loaded");

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        isPhone = YES;
    } else {
        isPhone = NO;
    }

    screenWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    screenHeight = self.frame.size.height;
    isOptionScreenOpen = NO;
    isPlayerStatsScreenOpen = NO;
    matchScreenButtonPressed = NO;
    [self showOptionScreenButton];
    [self showPlayerStatsScreenButton];
    [self matchViewControllerButton:matchScreenButton];
    [self deckViewerControllerButton:deckScreenButton];

}
return self;
```

}

```
-(IBAction)matchViewControllerButton:(UIButton *)sender{
CGRect rect;
UIFont *theFont;


if (isPhone == YES) {
    rect = CGRectMake(38, 150, 134, 116);
    theFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:22];
} else {
    rect = CGRectMake(275, 600, 200, 150);
    theFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:28];
}

matchScreenButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[matchScreenButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToMatchView:sender:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[matchScreenButton.titleLabel setFont:theFont];
[matchScreenButton setTitle:@"VS Comp" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
matchScreenButton.frame = rect;
[matchScreenButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[matchScreenButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MainMenuOptionButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self addSubview:matchScreenButton];
```

}

```
-(void)goToMatchView:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushToMatchView"]) {
    JDTHMatchScreen *vc2 = (JDTHMatchScreen *)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc2.name = self.textField.text;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A storyboard app has an entry in the info.plist file that tells the app that it's a storyboard app, and what the name of the storyboard is ("Main storyboard file base name" is the name of the key, and the value is the file name, without extension, of your storyboard). You would need to add this to your project to get it to recognize the storyboard. Also, non-storyboard apps usually have code in the app delegate to set up the initial controllers. This should be deleted for a storyboard app (the only code in the default template in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is "return YES"). It might be easier to just start a new storyboard based single view project and copy your files to it.

Comment: Thats good to know, and that is how my project is set up, but the main part of my question is still a problem. I need to move from one view in one view controller to another view in another view controller, and im not sure how to code this.

Comment: @JonHerbert, well if you've added the push segues it should be working now (assuming that your app is now recognizing your storyboard). Did you make those connection from a button to the next controller?

Comment: I did yes, ill edit my OP and put some of my code up there so you can see. In the storyboard i've made a button, which I then ctrl dragged to the MatchScreen ViewController. Now i already had code describe the look of the button and placement on the UIView (which is why this is all retroactive) and now i'm trying to place all of this info in there. Ill show you what i mean